# How to use Angular with HTML5 geolocation native API?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular-ui

I'm using following code snippet to obtain the current geolocation:

```
angular.module('HomelandApp').controller('PlacesController', function($scope,$http, $localStorage, uiGmapGoogleMapApi) {

  uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) {

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (pos) {
            $scope.map = { center: { latitude: pos.coords.latitude, longitude: pos.coords.longitude }, zoom: 17 };
        });
  });
});
```

The problem I'm facing is that I somehow have to *invoke the controller twice* in order to get the map rendered. This is happening when using `navigator` so it's not a pure Angular UI problem.

I guess they're digest cycle Angular against native JS details. How should I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`navigator.geolocation` is outside of angular core so any scope changes made within it need to notify angular to run a digest to update the view. There are several ways to do that.

Try:

```
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (pos) {
            $scope.map = { .... };
            $scope.$apply();
});
```

Comment: Could you update your question telling longer about those *several ways to do it*?

Comment: wrapping in `$timeout()` is another ... will call `$apply` internally but will be pushed to end of any existing digest cycle (if thre is one active)

Comment: More useful if you extend your answer ;)

Comment: I assure you there are lots of similar answers with a lot more detail around